# Spring MVC load many to many relations

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many

I got relations many to many between restaurant and tag. Here are my classes:

```
public class Restaurant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
(...)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="restaurant_tag",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")})
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

and:

```
public class Tag {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="restaurant_tag",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")})
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants;
```

I want to displays all the tags connected with my restaurant. Here's controller:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("tagList", restaurant.getTags());
```

In my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${tagList }" var="var"><c:out value="${var }" ></c:out></c:forEach>
```

When i go to the restaurant page, i got error:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:
>   failed to lazily initialize a
>   collection of role:
>   beans.Restaurant.tags, no session or
>   session was closed

Comment: I already told you in another question, but you probably didn't notice: your mapping is wrong. The same bidirectional association is mapped twice. One of the side should use the mappedBy attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your DAO closes the hibernate session before the collection can be fetched.

Have a look at the ["Open Session In View" pattern](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2010/03/open-session-in-view-pattern-spring-jpa/), this is the most common solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an open session in view pattern.  Add the first thing in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: then i got: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined